# On the probability of randomized testing covering all combinatorial testing interactions

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, software-testing

I'm interested in how fuzz testing and something called combinatorial testing. Combinatorial testing attempts to forgo exhaustive testing in favor of trying to test all possible "interactions" of a certain size. It's an interesting result that all interactions of a certain small size can be tested in far far fewer tests than the whole test space.

Define $V_n$ to be the set of binary vectors of size $n$, in other words $V_n = \{0,1\}^n$. This is intuitively the set of inputs that the tester might generate.

Define a $(k,n)$-template to be a subset of $\{0, ..., n-1\}$ of size $k$. Denote the set of $(k,n)$-templates as $I^k_n$. The intuition is that a $(k,n)$-template picks out $k$ variables out the $n$ variables.

Given a vector $v \in V_n$ and a $(k,n)$-template $T$ define $v[T]$ to be a new vector such that: $$v[T]_i = \begin{cases} 
      v_i & i \in T \\
      2 & i \not\in T
   \end{cases}$$
The intuition is that $v[T]$ is the specific $(k,n)$-interaction that $T$ picks out from $v$. The $2$ is needed to account for a "don't care" value. Without it $[1,1,1,1][{1,3}] = [0,1,0,0][{1,2}]]$ despite those tests sharing no two way interactions in common.

The set of $(k, n)$-interactions of a subset $X_n \subset V_n$ is $X_n[I^k_n] = \{ v[T] \mid v \in X_n \land T \in I^k_n\}$. Ideally when testing we want to pick $X_n$ such that $X_n[I^k_n] = V_n[I^k_n]$ as this would be we have tested all $(k, n)$-interactions

If I sample $N$ vectors uniformly from $V_n$ to form a subset $X_n$ what is the probability that $X_n[I^k_n] = V_n[I^k_n]$?

Some values I've worked out partially so far (case 2 determined using inclusion-exclusion) but I think there might be a bug in what I wrote so forgive me if these aren't accurate.
$$p(X_{n}[I^1_{n}] = V_{n}[I^1_{n}]) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 - 2\cdot\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}$$
$$p(X_{n}[I^2_{n}] = V_{n}[I^2_{n}]) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} 1 - 4\cdot(\frac{3}{4})^{N} + 6\cdot\frac{1}{2^N} - 4\cdot\frac{1}{4}$$

The general form seems to be something with roughly the following form

$$p(X_n[I^k_n] = V_n[I^k_n]) = \prod^{n} \ldots \prod^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{2^k-1}(-1)^i{2^k \choose i}(\frac{2^{k}-i}{2^k})^N$$

I have a few questions about this

1. Is this conjectured formula correct? If not what is the correct formula?
2. This conjecture is essentially a probability exponentially close to 1 multiplied by itself a tower of exponential number of times. I just have no intuition for how on earth this scales. Is there some way to get an idea for how this scales with $n$, $k$, and $N$? Can we maybe lower and upper bound this by something more intuitive?
3. (bonus) Here I've assumed uniform random sampling from $V_n$ with replacement but many fuzz checkers will actually bias their sampling in various ways. For instance you might keep sampling until $|X_n| = N$ by sampling without replacement. It seems intuitively clear to me that sampling with replacement yields a lower $p(X_n[I^k_n] = V_n[I^k_n])$ than sampling without replacement but not by much. How can we tell if a given set sampling technique will be higher or lower than the assumed default of sampling without replacement?
4. (bonus) Is there some related area of math or theory I should take a look at that might give further insight?

Comment: Are you familiar with the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: I think so? I used it to derive the k=2 case and then used a more general form of it as part of my conjectured formula but maybe I got it wrong. My formula appears to contain a version of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Special_case

Comment: Your formula looks suspiciously similar to the inclusion-exclusion principle. Try using this principle to prove your formula.

Comment: Try using the principle to prove the correctness of your formula.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake, thanks for catching that

Comment: Ok well I think I have pretty good evidence that I made a mistake somewhere actually. The first non-zero value of `p` for k = 3 and n = 10 is N=8 but I think the smallest such set I've seen is 13...but further more I've seen that this problem is NP-complete but I think you can determine if `p` is zero pretty efficiently so something in my belief set must be wrong and we shouldn't expect such a nice formula unless its very hard to determine if the result is non-zero. It could also be 1) its hard to compute if this is zero or 2) the source I have about N=13 and this being NP-hard is wrong